# Sinatra + Heroku: Store data >4k in a Session

Tags: session, heroku, sinatra, rack

I have a Sinatra app that will be running on Heroku.

It has a fairly long running method (approx 1 to 3 seconds) that creates a list of data. I've been storing this data in a session. So that when my user needs to access it again I avoid having to regenerate the list (they use it often).

In some instances the data is over 4k. Meaning that I can no longer store it in a session.

Rack::Session::Pool, works perfectly. Except that it is not compatible with heroku (since dynos do not share memory).

**Could someone suggest how I might best store this data?**

I've considered writing it to my SQL database, since a SELECT would be less expensive than the original generation of the list. There must be a better way?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a DB then how about something like Memcache - Heroku have a memcache addon that you could use.

Comment: Memcache through Heroku doesn't seem like the most cost effective option... considering the amount of data I'm expecting. I'm currently using a DB. Response times are around 100ms for the DB... in comparison to 30ms through a session. Not bad! Unless something better comes up, I'll probably be sticking to using a DB.